# Is break a code smell?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, code-quality

I'm asking in terms of a loop, obviously `break` is important in `switch` statements. Whether or not `switch` statements themselves are code smells is a separate issue.

So consider the following use cases for iterating a data structure:

1. You want to do something to the entire structure (no break needed)
2. You want to do something to part of a data structure.
3. You want to find something(s) in the data structure (which may or may not involve iterating the entire structure)

The above list seems more-or-less exhaustive to me, maybe I'm missing something there.

Case 1 can be thrown right out, we can use `map`/`forEach`. Case 2 sounds like `filter` or `reduce` would work. For case 3, needing to iterate the data structure to find something seems plain wrong, either the data structure itself should provide a relevant method or you are likely using the wrong data structure.

While not every javascript data structure (or implementation) has those methods it's trivially simple to write the relevant functions for pretty much any javascript data structure.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922599/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-break-in-a-for-loop) when researching but it is explicitly in the context of C/C++. I could understand how it would be more-or-less a necessity in C, but my understanding is that C++ has lambdas and many data structures are generally objects (e.g. `std::vector`, `std::map`), so I'm not sure I understand why the answers are all so universally in favor of `break` there, but I don't feel I know C++ well enough to even begin to comment.

I also realize that for some corner-case exceedingly large data structure the cost of iterating the entire structure may be unacceptably high, but I doubt those are very common when working even in node.js. Certainly it's the kind of thing you'd want to profile.

So I just don't see a use-case for `break` in today's javascript. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Not all loops iterate over the attributes of a data structure.

Comment: @KilianFoth looping a range of integers is semantically (although not performance-wise) equivalent to mapping over an array containing those integers: coffeescript for instance provides sugar to do exactly that `[0...5]` is equivalent to `[0,1,2,3,4]`. So repeating any action n times is essentially the same as calling `forEach` on an array of n elements.

Comment: I don't think that `break` and `filter` are interchangeable. In one case, you iterate *until* you encounter the first element that satisfies a predicate, in the second, you loop over *all* elements that satisfy a predicate. As in “cook me food on all days until Friday” versus “cook me food on all days that are work-days”.

Comment: @5gon12eder you'd use `reduce` to distill an array of elements down to the element that satisfies the predicate. You could even have total control over which element gets distilled: first match, last match, whatever. I already covered the performance implications of the difference in the question.

Comment: @JaredSmith Sure, you can simulate a lot of constructs via another one but that doesn't mean they are semantically equivalent. Just as you can replace `if (CONDITION) { STUFF; }` with `while (CONDITION) { STUFF; break; }`. It has the same effect but no the same meaning. And yes, this would be a terrible use of `break`. ;-)

Comment: @5gon12eder if you wrapped both approaches in a function that took a predicate and a data structure, would the difference in evaluation strategy matter to the caller? How are they not equivalent?

Comment: The first example that comes to mind is a "game loop" that's meant to run essentially forever, and `break;` is the simplest way to stop the loop when the user decides to quit.

Comment: @Ixrec that's a good one. Bit of a corner-case though, as it only applies to games. I would say that in the general case if you're hijacking javascript's event loop to sub in your own that in itself would be another smell.

Comment: In principle, pretty much any unbounded loop might need an explicit `if(iterations > max) break;` to ensure it doesn't hang the system, not just game loops. Such as interpreters which have a maximum recursion level, or linters which have a maximum number of errors they'll warn about before shutting up, etc. Kilian's original comment was basically correct.

Comment: You might want to use C#'s `TakeWhile` instead of `filter`/`Where` as your alternative.

Comment: @CodesInChaos although trivially easy to write using ES 6 iterators, it would be a custom function whereas the array operations are part of the spec and well-known enough that adding them for Sets, Maps, Objects (e.g. $.each) would be familiar to most javascript developers.

Comment: `map`, `foreach` and `filter` don't help when the problem is "operate on all elements up to the first one that satisfies some condition."  I'd go so far as to argue that using `reduce` for that case instead of a straight loop with a `break` is a code smell because it's less readable.

Comment: @Blrfl code smell does not mean sub-optimal solution. It means that something is *usually* wrong. And I while I agree that a for/while loop is best in that scenario, it is not *nearly* as common as 'do something to everything in this collection that passes the predicate test'. There will always be edge cases, including the event loop others have mentioned. This whole thing is getting onto the same track as the goto/eval argument. My question isn't whether or not break is *wrong*, but whether it invites scrutiny as there are *usually* better options.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Having a `break` out of a loop is no different than having that loop get refactored out to a function of its own and a `return` statement in a guard clause.

```
while(condition) {
  if(test) { break; }
  doStuff;
}
```

vs

```
doMuchStuff();

function doMuchStuff() {
  while(condition) {
    if(test) { return; }
    doStuff;
  }
}
```

Those are effectively the same.

Single keywords are not code smells. They are tools for flow control.  Many of them are variations on `goto` wrapped with some other level of safety to avoid the nightmare of spaghetti code.

In judging if a particular bit of code is problematic, it is necessary to look at how it works and if it is appropriate for the language constructs.  The key word alone is not sufficient to establish a code smell.  It might be a whiff in that it can be misused, but going on witch hunts because one sees a `switch` or `break` or some other flow control construct is counterproductive and leads to style guides that prevent people from writing understandable, straight forward code.

Comment: +1, with the caveat that there are a tiny handful of exceptions, such as `with`.

Comment: *“… going on witch hunts because one sees a `switch` or `break` or some other flow control construct is counterproductive and leads to style guides that prevent people from writing understandable, straight forward code.”* Totally agree; I think this really hits the nail.

Comment: @Ixrec: Yeah, JS `with` is a remarkable abomination, a brilliant exercise in fouling up a great idea.

Comment: Without the `break`, you have to create redundant code, or you have to create a function with a nested return, or you have to invert control and decrease the readability of your code drastically.

Comment: That's not a guard clause, it's in the while loop. For it to be a guard clause it has to be at the start of the function, What if test changes during dostuff? This basically becomes a function with multiple returns, which makes it "smelly". I find this to be a very bad example of a guard-clause.

Comment: @BobDalgleish: separating the loop into a separate function is almost always beneficial.

Comment: @Ixrec I'm not sure `with` counts as it is notoriously broken. Things like `eval` and `goto` may be problematic when used unwisely, but they are unambiguous.

Comment: @JaredSmith That's exactly why `with` counts in my mind; it's reasonable to say there are literally *no* situations where it makes sense to use `with`. `eval` and `goto` happen to have a very, very small number of legitimate uses, but personally I'm with Michael that "single keywords are not code smells", unless it's as universally bad as `with`. I'd have to see `eval` used without a clear and compelling justification for it before I'd call it a code smell. Of course "code smell" has no rigorous definition so you're free to use it differently.

Comment: @Ixrec That's what I mean, to me a code smell means 'probably bad' whereas `with` is unquestionably bad.

Comment: "Single keywords are not code smells. They are tools for flow control. " - N.B. This includes `goto` in languages that have it.

Comment: Bad example.  The problem with `break` is what happens *after* the end of your enclosing loop.  In your first example with a break, in the first line of code after the end of what you wrote, just what local variables are set to a valid state?  What external resources need to be closed?  In the `function()` example, the answers are hopefully (but admittedly not always) much simpler: **none** and **none**.

Answer (score 2):

@MichaelT asked how to rewrite the [C# example code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664758(v=vs.71).aspx) for goto without using goto.  Here is their code:

```
using System;
class Test
{
   static void Main(string[] args) {
      string[,] table = {
         {"Red", "Blue", "Green"},
         {"Monday", "Wednesday", "Friday"}
      };
      foreach (string str in args) {
         int row, colm;
         for (row = 0; row <= 1; ++row)
            for (colm = 0; colm <= 2; ++colm)
               if (str == table[row,colm])
                   goto done;
         Console.WriteLine("{0} not found", str);
         continue;
   done:
         Console.WriteLine("Found {0} at [{1}][{2}]", str, row, colm);
      }
   }
}
```

The first thing you notice is that, like much example/demo code, it prints the result.  *Any demo code that prints the result is B.S.*  Since hardly any real function ever prints the result.  It should return a result, modify an Object, append to a Stream, etc...

(Minor sidetrack...)  In this case, no big deal, but try "demo" Node.js code where you are deep inside a 3rd nested asynchronous callback, wondering how the heck that result is going to get used, and the demo just ignores the problem by printing something.  Grrr.  :-(

But, that gets you thinking.  That code is printing, and it is doing more than one thing.  Now, I'm less fanatic than many about Single Responsibility Principle, but, *if you are so stuck in the muck that a goto is looking good, you are violating SRP*.

Gee, what if I refactor, and write a general purpose function to search in a 2D array?  Here's the initial rewrite:  **Note** - I'm not a C# programmer, so this is in Java.

```
public class Test {

    public static void Main(String[] args) {
          String[][] table = {
             {"Red", "Blue", "Green"},
             {"Monday", "Wednesday", "Friday"}
          };
          for (String str : args) {
             int[] found = indexOf2D(table, str);
             if (found == null)
                 System.out.println(str + " not found");
             else
                 System.out.println(str + " found at " + found);
       }
    }


    public static int[] indexOf2D(Object[][] array, Object grail) {
        for (int r = 0; r<array.length; r++) {
            Object[] row = array[r];
            for (int c = 0; c<row.length; c++)
                if (grail.equals(row[c]))
                    return new int[] {r,c};
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now, in a real program, you'd refactor again, writing a general purpose "search in a 1D array" function.  And you'd test for null inputs.  You'd discuss returning null vs. a ["Null Object"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) vs. an Optional.  You end up with code that is a skillion times more versatile, more robust, and is cleanly factored.

And the code doesn't use a freaking goto.  As said before, *If your code is so complex that using a goto is required, your code is too complex*.

"Oh, but you've added two more method calls and an object creation, that will slow things down".  Bah.  If this is only getting called occasionally, the few extra nanoseconds don't matter.  And, if this code is time critical, maybe you should reconsider using an O(N) linear search through your 2D data structure.  :-)

### A comment on why **break/continue** are "more smelly" than **return**.

**Returns** are easier for the programmer to reason about.  You get out of the method, the stack and any local variables go away.  In effect, any "closure-like" information for that method vanishes and you don't have to worry about it.  (er, unless you opened up resources like files that need to be closed...)

With a **break** or **continue**, you jump forward in the code, but there is *still local state to remember*.  That can be hard.  Which local variables are still in scope?  What is the value at the end of the loop?  The programmer reading the code most hold the "closure" of that state in their head.

Closures are useful and cool, but better, in general, for the compiler or interpreter to hold all that state, not my feeble mind.

Comment: As an aside, Java doesn't need the goto that C# uses to get out of multiply nested structures, because it has the [labeled break and continue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html). Yes, they can be refactored into other calls without too much difficulty.

Comment: could you lose your mutiple returns with a while loop plus a GetNext method

Comment: I avoided getNext() because that is awkward when you need to return an index.  And mainly, I never bothered to learn and use that Java idiom cause it didn't seem worth the effort.  Just used the old "FORTRAN style" `for (int i=0 ...)`.  And apparently some high muckedy-mucks agreed, cause they added the wonderful "foreach style", ` for (T t : someCollectionOrArray);` which I do use.

Answer (score -6):

Yes, it is a 'code smell'.

This harks back to the days of spagettii code, gotos, sosubs and breaking out of loops to carry on with a procedure when ine of several conditions had been reached.

These practices have almost universaly been replaced with OO style methods, while, foreach and inhertiance. So if you still have break in your code you should ask yourself if you need it.

Obviously though 'code smell' is just an indicator that something *might* be wrong. Not a hard rule which can never be broken.

Also we should note that a function which returns from more than one place is also a code smell.

eg:

```
function doMuchStuff() {
  while(condition) {
    if(test) { return; }
    doStuff;
  }
}
```

should be

```
function doMuchStuff() {
  while(condition && !test) {
    doStuff;
  }
}
```

this is to avoid the kind of nightmare you can get into with

```
function doMuchStuff() {
  while(condition) {
    if(test) { return; }
    doStuff;
    if(test2) { return stuff; }
    doStuff2;
    if(test3) { return differentStuff; }
    doStuff3;
...etc
      }
    }
```

Comment: I think it should take more than just seeing a keyword like `break` to conclude a code smell..

Comment: "Also we should note that a function which returns from more than one place is also a code smell" - This (and your example) seems not really related to the original question anymore.

Comment: a code smell is not a bug or wrong, its an indication that there might be a problem. in this case increased complexity due to multiple possible exits from a loop

Comment: Early return is not a code-smell. Quite opposite, in fact. Now if that return was somewhat hidden, than we might talk, but the early return is still probably reducing complexity.

Comment: sure but in this case the early return is achieved with both the break and the while

Comment: A function with multiple returns is not necessarily a code smell. Want to see a code smell? Try six nested `if` statements, or the usage of a "control variable". Because that's what the "one return only" policy will create.

Comment: I think you have a misinterpretation of 'code smell' multiple returns is a code smell, in that it indicates you might have spagetti code(bad). But its only a smell, you might have early return null checking (fine)

Comment: Downvoted due to too many opinions with too weak argumentation. And I would add: It all depends on context. Even `goto` is the right tool in some situations.

Comment: im pretty sure goto would qualify as a code smell https://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: `goto` is not a code smell when there are no other forms of flow control that make sense for a given case. Don't be dogmatic. Not even Dijkstra was dogmatic about it in his essay. (Have you read it?)

Comment: Code is a code smell.  Don't write code.

Comment: `goto` is not necessarily bad even when there _are_ other options: **[GOTO still considered harmful?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/46586)** Of course, one should try to use the other options first, which will be better 99.9999% of the time. But for that 0.00001%, `goto` is useful.

Comment: Can't believe that 3 commenters put in plugs for `goto`.  Upvoted to try to cancel them out.  If your code is so complex that a goto seems a good way out, *your code is too complex.*

Comment: @user949300 you might want to give [Section 8.9.3 of the C# language specification a read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664758(v=vs.71).aspx) and consider the alternatives.

Comment: ?? obviously the statement is implemented, the question is whether its use can indicate bad coding

Comment: Ewan: I believe that @MichaelT is asking "how could you get out of this without using a goto?  Easy-peasy, see my answer.

Comment: @user949300 yep... and it [works](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11906082).  Though now you've got multiple returns in a method (or the arrow anti-pattern as some call it), though that gets us into another variation on the hunt for code smells and anti-patterns.